# Vim option for automatically inserting ">" at start of line

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a file `test.c` containing the following:

```
// line 1
// line 2
```

If I open this file in Vim and navigate to the first line in normal mode, then type `o`, I get the following:

```
// line 1
// 
// line 2
```

Now suppose I have a file `test.lhs` (literate Haskell) containing

```
> data X = A | B
> data Y = C | D
```

If I open this file and navigate to the first line in normal mode, then type `o`, I get

```
> data X = A | B

> data Y = C | D
```

**Question:** How can I make Vim automatically insert `>` at the start of the line for the `.lhs` file, similar to how `//` is automatically inserted for the `.c` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it! To `.vimrc`, add

```
set formatoptions+=o
```

This automatically inserts the "comment leader" (character sequence indicating a comment, or, in the case of literate Haskell, the Haskell code) at the start of the line.

For more information on the options accepted by `formatoptions`, type `:help fo-table`.

Comment: set formatoptions+=r will keep the setting on for line breaks too